# How to perform a hard refresh in current versions of Firefox, IE, Chrome and Safari for Windows and Mac OS X?

Tags: windows, macos, browser

How to perform a hard refresh in current versions of Firefox, IE, Chrome and Safari for Windows and Mac OS X (I guess this is a total of 8 questions)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Safari on OS X**

- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while pressing the reload button

**Chrome on OS X**

- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>, or <kbd>^</kbd> (or any additional modifier keys) while pressing the reload button

In Safari and Chrome you can see if any resources were loaded from a local cache by checking for `304 Not Modified` responses in the network tab of the web inspector.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache has instructions for common browsers on different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> for most of the browsers.